# Redrawing the highchart column type graph on ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

Actually i want to redraw the HighChart Bargraph on Ajax Success Function in which the parameter is send need help.

Below are my code

On Page Load Code (It Runs Perfect)

```
<script>
    var chart = $(function () {
        $('#chart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Overdue Projects'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: <?php print_r(isset($project) ? $project : []); ?>
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Hours'
                }
            },
            series: <?php print_r($series); ?>

        }, function (chart) { // on complete
            if (chart.series.length < 1) { // check series is empty
                console.log('Data Empty');
                chart.renderer.text('No Data Available', 380, 120)
                        .css({
                            color: '#4572A7',
                            fontSize: '16px'
                        })
                        .add();
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

On Ajax Success Function Code (Unable to Update the series and categories)

```
<script>
    $("select[name=GraphPro]").on('change', function () {
        var proId = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            data: 'proId=' + proId,
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('admin_dashboard/drawBarChart'); ?>",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (xyz)
            {
                var project = xyz.project;

                chart.series = xyz.series;

                var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(chart);

            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to update, or create a new chart? Because if you are trying to update, you need to use the update function on your chart variable, see http://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update.

Comment: @ewolden i want to update the graph on ajax success function with new categories and series value

Comment: chart exist and need to update the series and categories value of existing chart

Answer (score 1):

Really hard to say for sure without seeing the data in your variables what you are aiming for with the project variable.

That said, to update the chart (read: change) you can do the following assuming `chart` is the variable of your already existing chart;

**Updated as per your comment:**

```
<script>
$("select[name=GraphPro]").on('change', function () {
    var proId = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        data: 'proId=' + proId,
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('admin_dashboard/drawBarChart'); ?>",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(xyz) {
            console.log(xyz.project); //Value is ["Chat"] 
            console.log(xyz.series); // Value is [{"name":"Estimated Hours","data":[3]},{"name":"Consumed Hours","data":[12]}] 
            chart.update({ 
                xAxis:{ categories: xyz.project //print as xyz.project instead of above project value 
                }, 
                series: xyz.series // print as xyz.series instead of above series value 
                }); 
            }
    })
})
</script>
```

**Highchart API on update**: http://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

**Working example using update when button is clicked**: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/crhh39v6/

---

To add additional series to your chart you need to use `addSeries`, like this:

```
<script>
$("select[name=GraphPro]").on('change', function () {
    var proId = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        data: 'proId=' + proId,
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('admin_dashboard/drawBarChart'); ?>",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (xyz)
        {
            var project = xyz.project; //don't know what the plan with this variable is
            chart.addSeries(xyz.series);

        }
    })
})
</script>
```

**Highchart API on addChart**: http://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries

Comment: success:function(xyz)
            {
              console.log(xyz.project); //Value is ["Chat"]
              console.log(xyz.series); // Value is [{"name":"Estimated Hours","data":[3]},{"name":"Consumed Hours","data":[12]}]


              chart.update({
                  xAxis:{
                      categories: xyz.project //print as xyz.project instead of above project value
                  },
                  series: xyz.series // print as xyz.series instead of above series value
              });

            } Need Help

Comment: when i print in console.log the data prints perfect but the value is not coming in chart.update need help

Comment: Look at this example updating the chart when you click on the button: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/crhh39v6/ updating both the categories and the data. I copied your data in the comment.

Comment: Don't say thanks, accept and vote the answer, please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers